# Refreshing DIV with AngularJS and Rails on backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I use `ng-click' to use AngularJS to delete a post from my database.

```
%table.table{"ng-controller" => "PostsCtrl"}
  %tr
    %th Title
    %th ....
    %th
  - @posts.each do |post|
    %tr
      %td...
      %td= link_to 'Delete', '', 'ng-click' => "deletePost('#{post.id}')", :id => "post_#{post.id}"
```

This is in `/app/views/posts/index.html.haml`.

And the action for it:

```
 def index
   @posts = Post.all
 end
```

And now JS:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource']);
app.factory('Posts', function($resource){
 return $resource('/posts.json', {},{
    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    create: { method: 'POST' }
 })
});

app.factory('Post', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/posts/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
        'destroy': { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id', responseType: 'json'} }
    });
});
app.controller("PostsCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', 'Posts', 'Post', '$location', function($scope, $http, $resource, Posts, Post, $location) {

$scope.posts = Posts.query();
$scope.deletePost = function (post_id) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?")){
      Post.delete({ id: post_id }, function(){
        $scope.posts = Posts.query(); 

        $location.path('/');
        $scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

When I hit the link for deleting the post, the record is deleted from the database, but in the JS console is thrown the following error message:

```
DELETE http://localhost:3001/posts/5620a8766f85ce82ce000002 406 (Not Acceptable)
```

Here's the Rails action:

```
  def destroy
    puts "test"
    respond_with @post.destroy!
  end
```

And `routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

How to get rid of the error and refresh the table once the record is deleted?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I just found out that if I click the link to delete the respective post, AngularJS sends the request as HTML? Judging from what I see in terminal:

```
Processing by PostsController#destroy as HTML
...
ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say the 406 error indicates that your backend cannot respond with the requested format ( here HTML ).
A possible solution is to specify in your request the json format like :

note the `.json` after the `:id`

```
app.factory('Post', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/posts/:id.json", { id: '@id' }, {
        'destroy': { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id', responseType: 'json'} }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Yann, that was the trick! Such a small update and I fought with that for quite a long. Could I ask you, please, how to refresh the `PostsCtrl`? I need to manually refresh (F5) the page to see changes. `$scope.$apply();` doesn't work there.

Comment: I do not work with angular since a while, but the tip is to delete your post from your $scope.posts and do not try to query all your posts ( cause asynchronous request ). Have a look to lodash or underscore libraries this helps to work with javascript collections.